# Crosswalk Java to Javascript in shared mode

Tags: java, android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601087/crosswalk-call-js-function-from-java-on-android) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478434/crosswalk-call-java-method-from-javascript) an Android Java application may call Javascript functions using the `load` method from `XWalkView` class.

But I didn't find how to use this feature in **shared mode**. (as described here : https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/getting_started/run_on_android.html#shared-vs-embedded-mode)

Is there a way to retrieve the `XWalkView` class ?
May Crosswalk's extensions be a solution ?

Edited : in order to better explain this problem a sample project was created : https://github.com/gbourel/SampleCWShared

So the actual issue is how to call Javascript function from the XWalkRuntimeView returned by getRuntimeView() of XWalkRuntimeActivityBase class ?

Comment: I answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601087/crosswalk-call-js-function-from-java-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Class XWalkView is in the same package with your web resources and additional java code. In Crosswalk Library, there is class XWalkViewInternal communicating with XWalkView.

Comment: I agree but my first explanation wasn't sufficiently clear : the question is how to access the XWalkView class. I just add a comment to explain this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The method in runtime view has another name : the `XWalkRuntimeView.loadAppFromUrl()` method refers actually to the `XWalkView.load()` method.

Therefor calling `loadAppFromUrl('javascript:anyFunction()')` works as expected.